# How to get highlighted text from webpage with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a simple test extension for chrome. This is what should happen:

1. The user highlights some text
2. The user presses the extension and presses the button from the popup
3. There is an alert that shows the highlighted text

The problem is that the text gets deselected when the extension button is pressed, so the alert shows nothing. I have read many StackOverflow answers that relate to this problem, but I am new to JS and cannot figure it out.

These are my files:

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "Test",
"version": "1.0",
"manifest_version": 2,
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js":["content.js"],
    }
],
"browser_action":{
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Text Finder"
}


}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button>Show Text</button>
    <script src="popup.js" charset="ut-8"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}

return text
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', onclick, false)
 function onclick () {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},
    function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, getSelectionText())
    }
    )
 }
  }, false)
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request){
alert(request)
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to do this is to add an item to the context menu. For this, the user will select something, and right-click, and select your menu entry to send the selection to your extension.

```
chrome.contextMenus.create(
  id : 'selectionGetter',
  title : 'send selected text',
  contexts : ['selection'],
);

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info,tab) {
  //showing alert would require you to send a message to the active tab,
  //handle it in the contentscript and send alert from there

  //alternate lazy usage example:
  new Notification('My extension',{
    body : 'you selected: '+info.selectionText,
  });
});
```

Comment: Yep, this is actually a much better way to achieve what I want, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Save the last selected text in a variable, e.g. `selected` and `selectedBefore` than check both when you use them, whether either one is null, and use the appropriate one. You should probably set them to null after using them

popup.js

```
let lastSelected = null
let beforeLastSelected = null
...
// then set your variables, lets say in onClick event
beforeLastSelected = lastSelected
lastSelected = getSelectionText()
```

Comment: I was thinking to do that, but didn't know how to go about doing it. Where would I create this variable to keep track of the selected text?

Comment: for example, in your `popup.js` file, as global variables.